# How can I make webpack include unused functions with typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

How can I make webpack keep unused functions in the final file, I have functions in a typescript file that are not used in the typescript file, but I need them in the final file since they are used in events like `onclick` which need a function to execute, this is my webpack.config.js file:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        home: "./resources/js/home.ts",
        contact: "./resources/js/contact.ts",
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/js'),
        filename: '[name].js',
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.ts'],
    },
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [new TerserPlugin({
            extractComments: false,
        })],
    },
    watch: true,
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
        })
    ]
};
```

And this is my tsconfig.js file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "es6",
        "target": "es5",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "outDir": "./public/js",
        "rootDir": "./resources/js",
        "removeComments": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports":  true,
        "allowUnusedLabels": true,
    },
    "files": [
        "./resources/js/contact.ts",
    ],
}
```

I know the problem is webpack since when compiling using only typescript, I get the unused function in the final file. So how can I make webpack keep unused functions and leave them in the final javascript file?

Comment: Why do you add event handlers in html instead of using `addEventListener`?

Comment: @Konrad Because I'm using a javascript framework that uses events in html, and it seems to me that the code with that framework is cleaner and clearer, or so I personally think.

Comment: What is said framework? Maybe you should be tagging this question with that framework's tag?

Comment: @vera. It is a very small framework, it has no tag.

Comment: It's probably in the TerserPlugin settings. You'd have to dig through Terser's documentation to see if there's an option to whitelist specific stuff from the code cleanup or just disable that feature all together.